# Blazor login form password hash

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, hash, blazor, passwords

How can I force Blazor Server to pass the password from the page to the handler as a hash?

I am using

```html
<Input Text type="password/>
```

to enter password. And there is attribute

```html
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
```

in the model.
But it doesn't work. In the form handler i get the password in initial state.

```html
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject NavigationManager navManager;

<EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
    <div class="mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Email"
                   placeholder="Email"
                   id="email"
                   type="email"
                   class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Password"
                   placeholder="Password"
                   id="password"
                   type="password"
                   class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
    </div>
</EditForm>
     
@code{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress (ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MinLength (6, ErrorMessage = "Pasword min length is 6 charsters")]
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }

    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    private string LoginError = "";

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            loginModel.Email, loginModel.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
            navManager.NavigateTo("/");
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            LoginError = "Account is locked";
        else
            LoginError = "Ivalid Email or Password";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the definition of the class ***SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync*** which you are using, you can find the following codes and know how it works:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }
    return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
}
```

The input password is stored as plain text then it will be passed to the next password-verify step:

```
protected virtual async Task<PasswordVerificationResult> VerifyPasswordAsync(IUserPasswordStore<TUser> store, TUser user, string password)
{
    var hash = await store.GetPasswordHashAsync(user, CancellationToken);
    if (hash == null)
    {
        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
    return PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hash, password);
}
```

You can see from the code, the password will be hashed first then compare to the stored result. So your goal of hashing the password before the verifying can not be done. If you hash the password manually, it can not pass the verify step because the hashed result will be different from the stored result.